# javascript форматирование даты с учетом локального времени

Tags: javascript, дата

По запросу получаю переменную в таком формате:

```
var time = "25.07.2016 6:59:04";
```

Предполагается, что часовой пояс по умолчанию GMT0.

Подскажите, как мне вывести дату и время в таком же формате, только чтобы локальный пояс + летнее время были учтены?

Основная проблема, как дать понять функции, где в получаемой переменной 'time' день, а где месяц. Такой код работает, если число дня больше 12, но если дата, к примеру, 03.07.2016, день с месяцем меняются местами и теряется летний час (потому что меняется месяц, понятно).

```
var time = '13.07.2016 6:59:04';
var gmttime = Date.parse(time + 'GMT');
var d = new Date(gmttime);
var newdate = d.toString('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm');
alert(newdate);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге получилось справиться с задачей, правильно разбив строку time на элементы для указания нового формата. Может понадобиться кому.

```
<script src="http://datejs.googlecode.com/files/date.js"></script>
```

подключаем библиотеку date.js для того, чтобы в итоге проще вывести нужный формат времени 'dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss'

```
var time = "03.09.2016 6:59:04";  //день.месяц.год

var re = /\.|\s|:/;
var dateParts = time.split(re);    //разбиваем строку на элементы

var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0], dateParts[3], dateParts[4], dateParts[5]); //применяем полученные элементы
var gmtdate = new Date(date + 'GMT');  //указываем, что GMT0

document.write(gmtdate.toString('dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss')); //получаем 03.09.2016 9:59:04 (для GMT+3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var mytime = '12.11.2016 6:59:04';
var mytime2 = '03.07.2016 6:59:04';

var x = new Date(Date.parse(mytime + 'GMT')).valueOf();
var y = new Date(Date.parse(mytime2 + 'GMT')).valueOf();

document.write((new Date(x)).toString('MM.d.yyyy HH:mm:ss'));
document.write('<br/>');
document.write((new Date(y)).toString('MM.d.yyyy HH:mm:ss'));
```

```html
<script src="http://datejs.googlecode.com/files/date.js"></script>
```

Comment: Не решает проблемы определения дня и месяца. Просто вы на первое место месяц поставили.

Answer (score 0):

Разделить строку time по пробелу, потом две строки по точкам и двоеточиям.
Пропустить это через метод [Date.UTC()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) - получится новая дата без учёта сдвига. Сделать этой дате [getTimezoneOffset()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) и прибавить его к дате без сдвига. Преобразовать дату в строку, заново разделить как надо, пересобрать и присвоить time.

Comment: Собственно, правильно разбить строку на элементы и присвоить их новому формату и было проблемой.  В итоге получилось то что нужно,   и даже без getTimezoneOffset().